# Texels vs Units vs Pixels in Lightmaps?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So in the configurations of the **Lightmapping** I have a lot of strange settings and can't quite understand how they work together:

- **First off texels = pixels, right? So texel is just a fancy name for a
  pixel?**
- **Lightmap Resolution in texels per unit.** What is **unit** in this
  context? And how does it fit that stuff in the constant Lightmap Size
  (let's say 256 texels=pixels)?
- What is the difference between **Indirect Resolution** and **Lightmap Resolution**? And why I can't adjust **Indirect Resolution** in Progressive CPU?

Comment: `A texel, texture element, or texture pixel is the fundamental unit of a texture map...` from Wikipedia. As to the second, Unity Units (basically, 1 meter, its those numbers in the transform inspector). Third, don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Indirect resolution is the fidelity of indirect lighting, light that comes from stuff like a bright surface being lit by the sun. Lightmap resolution is the fidelity of general lighting (basically direct lights)

I'm fairly sure You can't set it in progressive CPU because it'll eventually reach your lightmap resolution anyway. Progressive CPU does a low quality lighting pass as you edit your scene, and over time improves the quality, so you can get a rough idea of your lighting as you edit, but eventually (particularly in areas you aren't playing around in) the lighting will reach your max resolution. It's purely to improve your workflow, so you can edit your scene without waiting for a slow light pass.

I recommend reading the relevant pages:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProgressiveLightmapper.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lightmapping.html

Unity's lighting system is powerful, but also quite complex, take your time and read up on the documentation, when I first started working with it I spent a few days just absorbing all the information, there's a lot to take in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please clarify how **indirect resolution is going to reach the lightmap resolution part?** As I understand lightmap res is the number of pixels/texels that Unity gives to each unit of the surface. Then it puts all of this generated and calculated texels into multiple or one lightmap(s). What is the point of indirect resolution here if I only get a single collection of lightmaps **(one collection = one resolution = one variable)?**

Comment: Basically indirect lighting is *really* expensive to calculate, so the resolution of your indirect lighting is significantly lower than your direct lighting, so lighting passes dont take days. Luckily, in the real world indirect lighting is very soft, so the lower resolution doesn't really matter too much because it's normally a blurry soft light.As for how it "reaches" that level, the progressive lighting flow is always re-calculating lighting at higher and higher resolutions over time, so the resolution naturally rises as the scene is calculated and re-calculated, idk the upper limit though.